# How to count how many checkboxes has been checked

Tags: jquery

I have an `HTML` table the first column consists of `checkboxes` etc when the user clicks a button I want to check if any of the checkboxes have been `checked` before going to the code behind etc.

This is what I have but it keeps throwing an `error`

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input.checkbox:checked"]
```

This is my code I just want to return the count of how many checkboxes are actually checked.

```
       $('#BtnExportToExcel').click(function () {
              var check = ('#gvPerformanceResult').find('input.checkbox:checked"]').length;
              alert(check);
        return false;
        }):
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have a dangling bracket in the `find()` function, try this

```
$('#BtnExportToExcel').click(function () {
   var check = $('#gvPerformanceResult').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
   alert(check);
   return false;
}):
```

Note, based on your answer it seems you want ALL checkboxes within `#gvPerformanceResult` and not checkboxes with the class `.checkbox` - use `[type=checkbox]` to select those checkboxes

Comment: Please correct the errors in your code (as Curt has pointed out in his answer).

Answer (score 19):

You have invalid syntax (No `$` at the start, and `"]` at the end).

Change:

```
('#gvPerformanceResult').find('input.checkbox:checked"]').length;
```

To:

```
$('#gvPerformanceResult').find('input.checkbox:checked').length;
```

Comment: Does this solution work in all browsers like IE? Sometimes we don't have time to test in all browsers manually. It would be better if someone has tested already.

Answer (score 11):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
```

This will return the number of checked checkbox.

---

Restrict:

```
$('#gvPerformanceResult').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
```

Comment: This will return all checked checkboxes on the page, not just in `#gvPerformanceResult`

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out

```
$('#BtnExportToExcel').click(function () {
    var check = $("input:checkbox:checked").length
    alert(check);
});
```

Comment: Note: This will be all check boxes on your page. Not just inside `#gvPerformanceResult`

Comment: See my answer, itll find all checked checkboxes within `#gvPerformanceResult`

Comment: You figured it out? Or the other answers did it for you? I don't think it is appropriate to post an answer to your own question when it has already been sufficiently answered by everyone else.

Comment: I didnt refresh the page to check for any notifications so when i posted my answer it then showed all the other answer, Chris i have decided to use your answer, due to later on other people may add checkboxes else where on the page, and i dont want them to be associated with the gvperformanceresult table.