# Validation to check if at least one checkbox is selected from a jquery datatable using javascript

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help with my javascript code below I am trying to write a validation for the user to select at least on checkbox . the validation works when I don't select a checkbox but when I do select one I still have the alert message

HTML Code

```
    <div id="ichildticket" class="panel panel-primary" style="display:none">
        <div class="panel-heading" >    
         <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseFive1" aria-expanded="false">
             <i class="fa fa-child fa-fw"></i> Select Child Tickets to Close <i class="pull-right fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </a>
         </h4>
     </div>
   <div id="collapseFive1" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel">
     <div class="panel-body">
       <span id="SelectTicket" style="color:red"></span>
          <div class="col-md-12">
          <table id="childtable" class="table table-condensed table-striped" style="width: 100% !important;"></table>
         </div>
    </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn-block " id="btnSubmit" />
      </div>
  </div>
```

Javascript

```
        $(function () {
        $('input[id$=btnSubmit]').click(function (ze) {
            $('#childtable').find("tbody tr").each(function () {
               var row = $(this);
                var vcheckBox = document.getElementById("childticket");
                var checkboxs = row.find($(':checkbox:checked'));
                var okay = false;
                for (var i = 0, l = checkboxs.length; i < l; i++) {
                    if (vcheckBox.checked == true && checkboxs[i].checked) {
                        okay = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!okay) {
                    alert("At least One Child Ticket Should Be Selected");                        
                    ze.preventDefault();
                }
                else {
                    alert("Checkbox Selected");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Jquery table image

[image]

Comment: Add your html code also

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the checkboxs from the table parent and figure out how many of them are checked.  If you have more than 0, so there is at least one checkbox checked else the user did not select anything.
Something like this:

```
var check = $('#tablename').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
if (check>0) {
    alert("Checkbox Selected");
else{
    alert("At least One Child Ticket Should Be Selected");                        
    ze.preventDefault();
}
```

A similar question was already on stackoverflow: [How to count how many checkboxes has been checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11861024/how-to-count-how-many-checkboxes-has-been-checked).

Comment: this is not working for me if you look at my code I have 2 checkbox in my if statement I need to check if vcheckBox is true and checkboxs <0 but you code only checked for one checkbox. any help with this issue please?

Answer (score 0):

If you love pure Javascript to have all over your project. this might help you I guess
Javascript code

```
 let obj =  document.getElementById("clickevent");
let btn = document.getElementById("btnhit");
let holdvalue = [];
obj.addEventListener("click",function(even){
        holdvalue.push(even.target.value);

});
btn.addEventListener("click",function(even){
    if(holdvalue.length  !== 0)
    {
        holdvalue.forEach(function(item){
     alert(item);
      });
    }
    else

    alert("you have not selected any item yet");

});
```

HtML code

```
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <form>

           <div class="form-group" id="clickevent">
               <input type="checkbox" class="myche" value="1">
               <input type="checkbox" class="myche" value="2">
               <input type="checkbox" class="myche" value="3">
               <input type="checkbox" class="myche" value="4">
               <input type="checkbox" class="myche" value="5">
               <input type="checkbox" class="myche" value="6">
           </div>
           <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button" id="btnhit">
            Hit the button
           </button>
        </form>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```